# accessing a servlet by multiple clients

Tags: java, servlets

i want to create a servlet which generates a random number and asks user to guess it. and outputs if the number is greater or lesser and shows the number of times the user has failed.

what i did was,

i inputted a number using form.

i generated a random number in init function, and initiated the count to zero there. and in the doGet method i compared both numbers and i again wrote back a html page asking for the number with failure count.

it works well with one client. but when multiple clients access the same servlet every one will get same random number.

i read that the servlet is instantiated just once. is there a way by which many clients can access the servlet and every one of them get different random numbers. is it even possible? is so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow associate the session of the client with the random number. You can access the jsessionid generated by web application containers. Map it with your random number.

Comment: is it possible with out session?

Comment: you can associate each client with a unique id by yourself which will be sent each time with the users input to the servlet. first time the user enters the site, create the id an build your page content in the servlet with that id.

Comment: You can simulate the Session by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in your case is to use session parameters. Session will be created for each user, so you can have a parameter for each session(user).

To create a new session if it is not already exist:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("randomValue","YOUR VALUE HERE");
```

By this code you can read parameter from session context on the next request:

```
    request.getSession(false).getAttribute("randomValue");
```

You can "save" count the same way.